# Higher-order function returning function returning nothing

Tags: c#

In C# how do I define function which return function which returns nothing? Something like this:

```
class X
{
    public Func<void> GetFuncReturningVoid() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A function returning nothing is an `Action`. Using a lambda expression, you could write this:

```
Action GetFuncReturningVoid() {
    return () => Console.Writeline("my action");
}
```

And if you need to accept arguments...

```
Action<int, int> GetActionWithArguments() {
    return (int x, int y) => Console.Writeline(x * y);
}
```

Or you can let the compiler infer the types:

```
Action<int, int> GetActionWithArguments() {
    return (x, y) => Console.Writeline(x * y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, `Action`s are "actions": they do something, but return nothing. `Func`s are "functions," in the mathematical sense: they transform one value into another.

So you want something like `Action`, or `Action<T>` (for one argument of type `T`), or `Action<T, U>`, etc.